# Проблема с toLowerCase()

Tags: javascript

```
// Выбираем случайное слово из массива
var words = ["программа", "процессор", "прекрасный", "робот"];
var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
// Неугаданные буквы
var remainingLetters = word.length;
// Попытки
var remainingAttempt = 3;
// Создаем массив ответов и заполняем его
var answerArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    answerArray[i] = "_";
};

// Основной цикл программы
while (remainingLetters > 0 && remainingAttempt > 0) {
    alert('Текущее слово : ' + answerArray.join(" "));
    var guess = prompt("Угадайте букву или нажмите отмена для выхода из игры.");
    guess.toLowerCase(); // проблема здесь
    console.log(guess);
    if (guess === null) {
        break;
    } else if (guess.length !== 1) {
        alert("Пожайлуста, введите только одну букву.");
    } else {
        for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
            if (word[j] === guess) {
                if (answerArray[j] === '_') {
                    answerArray[j] = guess;
                    remainingLetters--;
                    alert("Вы угадали букву!");
                } else {
                    alert("Вы уже угадали эту букву!");
                }
            } else {
                remainingAttempt--;
                alert('Попыток осталось ' + remainingAttempt);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}


alert('Результат : ' + answerArray.join(" "));
alert("Конец игры! Было загадано слово " + word);
```

Помогите разобраться, почему к большой букве полученной через prompt не применяется toLowerCase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В JS строки не изменяемые. Вы должны присвоить результат вызова `toLowerCase` какой-нибудь переменной или даже той же самой переменной. Например

```
guess = guess.toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 1):

Метод toLowerCase() возвращает измененную строку, а не изменяет значение переменной.

```
console.log(guess.toLowerCase());
```